# Jquery : find an element from another found element

Tags: jquery

Sorry if the title isn't clear but I could not find a simple way to describe my problem. I'm struggling with a jquery request.

I need to find the first td element before the first td element that is empty and change its background color.

I figured out how to find the first empty td and change its background color (I don't want to change this element background color, that was just in order to have the end of my request):

`$('table').find('td:empty:first').css({"background-color": "lime"});`

But I don't know how to get the first td before this element.

Comment: Try closest() : https://api.jquery.com/closest/ or prevAll() : https://api.jquery.com/prevall/

Comment: How about `$('table').find('td:empty:first').prev().css({"background-color": "lime"});`? Assuming, of course, that the found `td` is not the first `td` in its row (`tr`).

Comment: It worked. Thank you. I thought it would only search for a similar element, so an empty td element.